# Prove that a * a standard normal + b * an independent standard normal is $\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$ * a standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, characteristic-functions

I am learning about characteristic functions and am confused of how to show a statement in the lecture notes using characteristic functions:

a times a standard normal + b times an independent standard normal = $\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$ times a standard normal.

I'd appreciate if someone could let me know why this can be proven using characteristic functions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are asking for the *standard deviation* of $aX+bY$?

Comment: Hey, yes. I think the argument in the notes refers to the sum being ~N(0, $\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$).

Comment: It is necessary to use characteristic function. I´m asking since it is not necessary.

Comment: Hey, yes using characteristic function is not necessary here, but I want to know if there is a way to use characteristic function to prove it. thanks

Comment: I don´t know what the advantage is by using the characteristic. I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: I have added the content of your comments to the question, if you feel I have made a mistake, please feel free to undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the characteristic function of a sum of **independent** random variables is the product of the characteristic functions: writing $Ee^{itX} = \phi_X(t)$,

$$ \phi_{aX + bY}(t) = \phi_{aX}(t) \phi_{bY}(t)$$
Recall that the characteristic function of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is
$$ \phi_{N(\mu,\sigma^2)}(t)=e^{it\mu  - \frac{1}2\sigma^2 t^2}.$$
So if $X,Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$, we have $aX \sim N(0,a^2)$ and $bY \sim N(0,b^2)$, and therefore
$$ \phi_{aX + bY}(t) = e^{-\frac12(a^2 + b^2)t^2}$$
but this is the characteristic function of $N(0,a^2 + b^2)$, which means that $aX+bY\sim N(0,a^2 + b^2) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! What I didn't remember to use is that 'the characteristic function of a sum is the product of the characteristic functions'.

Comment: @Teemo you're welcome :)

Comment: It should be mentioned, that sum to product formula works (in general) when $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: @DominikKutek oops, thanks for catching the slip!